# How to start a celery worker that only pushes tasks to the broker but does not consume them?

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have the main producer of tasks in a webserver. I do not want the webserver to consume any tasks, so it should only send the tasks to the broker which get consumed by other nodes.

Right now I route tasks using the -Q option in the nodes by specifying the particular queues for each node. Is there a way to specify 0 queues for a worker?

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Is the webserver running as a celery worker? If so, why?

Comment: Umm, I do not need to run a worker to just push tasks to the broker right?

Comment: no. but you say "I do not want the webserver to consume any tasks" - it can only consume tasks if it is running as a celery worker. hence my question

Comment: if you specify 0 queues for a worker it will consume nothing and do nothing. why would you want this?

Comment: Youre right, I though it was mandatory to start a worker even to push tasks to the broker, obviously I was wrong, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use a worker to push tasks to the broker - you can do that from a regular python process.